# Please can anyone list all the HTTP headers

Tags: tcp, squid

Hi guys I don't know where to put this.
I searched the internet but didn't find any relevant information. I'm just trying to learn and implement a few known headers like,

```
X-Online-Host 
X-Forwarded-For 
Host
```

I need to know more headers like these. Specifically header which defines Username and Password field. I can provide additional information if anyone is interested. A list with detailed info would be great, If someone has a journal like repository on this context.

Comment: Oh great!.. That resource is great. @PaulK you guessed right, I was talking about HTTP headers. I thought all headers started with a "X-". Actually I've created an android APP but then I wanted to make it work in my college network , where it requires proxy authentication like User : Pass. My college uses Squid proxy/caching. Im going through their website (http://www.squid-cache.org/) at this moment .. But its a bit confusing as I'm new to this headers and stuff.

Comment: RFCs exist for a reason. You shouldn't be be asking for *another* list.

Answer (score 2):

A definitive list can be found here: https://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

First 2 hits from a search engine.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Answer (score 0):

I take it you mean HTTP headers? In that case, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)'s a list of HTTP header fields. The "X-" is just a convention to indicate a header's non-standard status.